# How to fix when I activate my VPN, it also connects to what the network manager says is unknown

Tags: linux-mint, openvpn

I'm using IPVanish, and I can give you the config files if you need them, but I'm pretty sure it is configured right. Also I've tried multiple servers.

[image: Unknown Connection]

Comment: Instead of Unknown, what do you expect to see?

Comment: Nothing. I'm connected to NYC 29 OpenVPN. "unknown" is a byproduct. I have no idea why I'm connected to it. I'm thinking it might be a DNS leak.